# fullcalendar get selection

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) control in a website . I have enabled selection so that if the user selects /or clicks on a day, that selection is highlighted. After the user selects a day or days I want to have a button that is not part of the calendar control, to have a click event and when the user clicks on that button I want to alert the start and end date to the user

I do not want to use the "select" callback.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer if someone needs it.I used the select event ,to set hiddenfields with the dates, on the button click i then just use the values in the hiddenfields

```
  var calender = $('#calender').fullCalendar({
            eventClick: function (event) {
                alert('Event Start' + event.start);
            },
            editable: true,
            events: "../Leave/Ajax/LeaveForMonth.ashx",
            selectable: true,
            unselectAuto: false,
            select: function (startDate, endDate) {
                $(".hidSelectionStart").val(startDate);
                $(".hidSelectionEnd").val(endDate);
                $("#bnAddLeave").show();
            }
        });

enter code here
```